# Mounted wrong drives.. is this fixable?

Tags: partitioning, mount

I have a dedicated server running on Ubuntu with Kimsufi, and I believe I may have mounted the wrong drives when I was setting up.

My "/" directory is full, and a smaller drive was mounted on it.

```
Filesystem      1K-blocks      Used  Available Use% Mounted on
udev              4001828         0    4001828   0% /dev
tmpfs              806528       736     805792   1% /run
/dev/sda2        20026236  18986056          0 100% /
tmpfs             4032620         8    4032612   1% /dev/shm
tmpfs                5120         0       5120   0% /run/lock
tmpfs             4032620         0    4032620   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/sda1          498532    216982     251291  47% /boot
/dev/sda3      1901536420 431092728 1373828220  24% /home
tmpfs              806524         0     806524   0% /run/user/1003
```

Is there a way for me to rearrange or partition the drives in a safe way that will retain all my files and directory?

Can I swap my sda2 and sda3?

Comment: You cannot make partition changes without some risk. And hard drives eventually fail, so if any of your data is important, you must have regular good backups. But what is filling / (root). My / is 8GB used in my 25GB / partition and all my data is in my data partition(s). You have a lot of data in /home partition and more that current /, so you could not swap anyway. You may be able to shrink sda3 and then move it right to make more room to expand sda2. But move of sda3 will be very slow as it has lots of data. You must use live install as you cannot change mounted partitions.

Comment: Welcome Andy. I agree with oldfred. Though, as a time buying workaround you might (if you know what you are doing!) be able to boot into a recovery mode, drop into root shell, then use bind mounts. You would for instance move [copy, check, then delete] large folders from / to /home. Then you could use bind mounts to make a reference from e.g. /largefolder to /home/largefolder. With a tool like ncdu you could determine what folders take up the most space. Bind mounts can be made permanent within /etc/fstab. Do take care though in which folders you would use bind mounts for (e.g. not /dev/*).